# finding mismatches between dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a reference dataframe called ref. I would like to compare the elements in ref with a set of dataframes and then insert the mismatches in lists. The values are 0, 1 and NA. Sample dataset below:

```
ref <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("bar", 
"foo", "hello"), class = "factor"), a = c(1, 0, 0), b = c(1, 
1, 0), c = c(1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(2:1, .Label = c("bar", "foo"), class = "factor"), 
    b = c(0, 0), f = c(NA, 0), a = c(1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

**ref:**

> ```
>      ID a b c
> 1   foo 1 1 1
> 2   bar 0 1 1
> 3 hello 0 0 1
> ```

**df1**

> ```
>    ID b f  a
> 1 foo 0 NA 1
> 2 bar 0 0  1
> ```

The dataframes are not ordered. The ref IDs are all inclusive. The goal is to compare the elements with the same ID and colname and make a list of mismatches based on colname. The desired list for df1 would be:

**df1_list**

> ```
> $a
> [1] "bar"
>
> $b
> [1] "foo" "bar"
> ```

The main issue is that column names aren't all the same and not in order. And it gets fairly complicated if I were to do this for each of the many dataframes. I couldn't solve this with join functions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with base R :

```
cols <- intersect(names(df1[-1]), names(ref[-1]))
rows <- match(df1$ID, ref$ID)
apply(df1[cols] != ref[rows, cols], 2, function(x) as.character(df1$ID[x]))

#$b
#[1] "foo" "bar"

#$a
#[1] "bar"
```

Comment: The one problem I ran into is that my logical df1[cols] != ref[rows, cols] matrix has NAs. Is there an easy way to set those to false?

Comment: @user171558 If it's only `df1` that has `NA`s you can do `apply(df1[cols] != ref[rows, cols] & !is.na(df1[cols]), 2, function(x) as.character(df1$ID[x]))`

Comment: The ref has NAs

Comment: @user171558 In that case do `mat <- df1[cols] != ref[rows, cols]` and then `apply(mat & !is.na(mat), 2, function(x) as.character(df1$ID[x]))`